# How to convert string type to my own user class type in java

Tags: java, casting

I have two classes like FirstClass and SecondClass. In the FirstClass I declared a variable with String type and then I assigned that variable to the SecondClass type. But it shows an exception. Please help.

Here is the code.

FirstClass.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SecondClass sc;
    String a = "world";
    Object obj = a;
    sc = (SecondClass) obj;
    System.out.println("" + sc);   
}
```

ErrorMessage.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.study.SecondClass
at com.study.FirstClass.main(FirstClass.java:13)
```

Comment: You should go through the basics of OOP

Answer (score 1):

Java is very strongly typed.  There's no way to do this in Java.  Java remembers the type - "world" is not a `SecondClass` object and can't be forced into it.

Even if you had two classes that were identical, say `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` - you still couldn't convert between them using this approach.

One thing you could do though would be to add a constructor in SecondClass that took a String and would give you an object of type SecondClass based on that String.  But even then, the String and the SecondClass object would be distinct.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object obj = a;
sc = (SecondClass) obj;
```

At compile time you are telling java compiler that your object obj is in fact an object of class SecondClass. So it would compile fine. But at runtime it will know that obj is not an instance of SecondClass. So it would throw Exception at runtime. You just cannot cast anything to anything.

Usecase :

Type casting makes sense in case of polymorphism. For example you have used polymorphic reference to subclass object. At a later point of time you need to use some function that is defined and implemented only in the subclass. Then you need to type cast it to that subclass(which in fact your object is) and then you call the required function on it.